# Vue - Retrieve events and v-model from component

Tags: vue.js

I'm fairly new to Vue and I wanted to have a reusable component for `v-select` (using vuetify). Now the problem is I don't know how to pass the `v-model` and `@events` to the component. Here is my code below.

**Template.vue**

```html
      <base-select 
           v-model="rows.corporate_objective_id"
           :items="corporate_objectives" 
           :item-text="corporate_objective" 
           :item-value="id" 
           placeholder="Please select a Corporate Objective"
           @change='corporateObjectiveDescription(); departmentObjectives()'
         />
```

**v-select component**

```html
    <template>
      <v-select
        :value="value" 
        @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
        :items="items" 
        :item-text="item-text" 
        :item-value="item-value" 
        dense
        clearable
      />
    </template>

    <script>
     export default {
        name: 'BaseSelect',
        props: ['value', 'items', 'item-text', 'item-value'],
        data: () => ({
        })
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: check this resource, it is really good to understand v-model and how to implement it in custom components: https://alligator.io/vuejs/add-v-model-support/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass all the attributes and listeners to the child component writing this:

```
<template>
  <v-select
    v-bind="$attrs"
    v-on="$listeners"
    dense
    clearable
  />
</template>

<script>
 export default {
    name: 'BaseSelect',
    data: () => ({
    })
  }
</script>
```

You can look at [this video](https://youtu.be/7YZ5DwlLSt8?t=1310) from `21:50`. It explains very well how to make "transparent wrappers"

Comment: This makes things really easier. Thank you very much!